# App Engine model filtering with Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-models

hi i am using django app engine patch i have set up a simple model as follows

```
class Intake(db.Model):
    intake=db.StringProperty(multiline=False, required=True)
    #@permerlink 
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return "/timekeeper/%s/" % self.intake
    class Meta:
       db_table = "Intake"
       verbose_name_plural = "Intakes"
       ordering = ['intake']
```

i am using the following views to check if some thing exist in data base and add to database

```
from ragendja.template import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from google.appengine.ext import db
from timekeeper.forms import *
from timekeeper.models import *

def checkintake(request, key):
    intake = Intake.all().filter('intake=',key).count()
    if intake<1:
       return HttpResponse('ok')
    else:
       return HttpResponse('Exist in database')

def addintake(request,key):
    if Intake.all().filter('intake=',key).count()>1:
        return HttpResponse('Item already Exist in Database')
    else:
        data = Intake(intake=cleaned_data[key])
        data.put()
        return HttpResponse('Ok')
```

i can add to database with no problem (when i do a `Intake.all().count()` it increases) but when i check if the key exist in the database by filtering i am getting a count of zero any one have any idea why i am not able to filter by keys ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert a space between the field name and the operator in your filter arguments - eg, use `.filter('intake =')` instead of `.filter('intake=')`. With an equality filter, you can also leave it out entirely, as in `.filter('intake')`. Without the space, the equals sign is taken to be part of the field name.